# How I can set coordinates for messagebox in tkinter without tk window

Tags: python, tkinter, root, tk-toolkit, messagebox

```
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from tkinter import *
     
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x400+500+50000')
    root.mainloop()

    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message")
```

messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message")
But there only tk window coordinate, but I need coordinates for messagebox and without tk window

Comment: Even with a `tkinter` window, I don't think this is possible, unless you make a custom messagebox.

Comment: You cannot specify the coordinates of a messagebox.

Comment: If you are working under MS Windows, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50086178/13629335)